# Traefik custom error pages when using Docker labels

Tags: docker, traefik

Later versions of Traefik support custom error pages – the ability to send a request to a different back end if there is an error. Commonly, this is a 502 when the reverse proxy can't communicate with a an application server. [This](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/configuration/commons.md#custom-error-pages) docs page explains how to do this with the `file` backend type, and this works well enough.

However, I'm trying to use the Docker backend. [This](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/configuration/backends/docker.md) docs page shows a prospective Docker configuration – though it's not clear what the `<name>` substitution is supposed to mean.

So, using Docker Compose, I've got a basic setup where I want to direct all HTTP 500-599 traffic to an alternate backend, called `error`. Here's what I've got in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./acme:/etc/traefik/acme/
      - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
  hello:
    image: kitematic/hello-world-nginx
    ports: 
      - "80"
    labels:
      - traefik.backend=hello
      - traefik.port=801
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.errors.network.status=["500-599"]
      - traefik.frontend.errors.network.backend="error"
      - traefik.frontend.errors.network.query="/500s.html"
  error:
    image: kitematic/hello-world-nginx
    ports: 
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - ./html:/website_files
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=error"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:error.localhost"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
```

As you can see, I've got a deliberate mismatch on the `hello` container between its published port and the port that Traefik is looking for. This is to force a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

My `traefik.toml` file looks like this:

```
# defaultEntryPoints must be at the top because it should not be in any table below
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
# [accessLog]
logLevel = "DEBUG"

[web]
# Port for the status page
address = ":8080"

# Entrypoints, http and https
[entryPoints]

[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "localhost"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = true
# swarmmode = true
```

But, a request to `http://localhost` still returns the generic `Bad gateway` message, rather than redirecting to the `/500s.html` served by the `error` container (which works fine by going directly to http://error.localhost/500s.html)

Thank you anyone for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Error pages with labels are not available in 1.5: https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers

The support come in 1.6: https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers

Comment: That was definitely part of the problem @Idez. So, I've gotten past that, and also figured out that the labels need to be `errors.networks`, not errors.network.

Comment: But... now it's telling me `Error Page is configured for Frontend frontend-Host-localhost-0, but either Backend error is not set or Backend URL is missing` – even though I have a backend called `error`. Any more thoughts?

Comment: Check your traefik montioring gui - it will have the full generated name of the backend for error listed. 

I, for example, had dev-env_error, but it was changed to be dev-env-error